# "break" dentro de um if-else encadeado

Tags: java

Sou novo por aqui e tenho uma dúvida bem simples: existe algum tipo de "`break`" para que possa ser utilizado dentro de um `if-else` encadeado?

```
if (valor > getSaldo()) {
    System.out.println("Valor informado maior que o saldo");
} else {
    setSaldo(saldo - valor);
}
if (getSaldo() < 50000) {
    setCategoria(SILVER);
} else if (getSaldo() < 200000) {
    setCategoria(GOLD);
} else {
    setCategoria(PLATINUM);
}
```

Exemplo: tenho saldo de 200000 (categoria platinum). Se eu remover 160000, eu deveria ficar na categoria GOLD pois não posso "cair" duas vezes

Comment: O que você deseja alcançar com esse "`break`"?

Comment: Então, preciso que seja setado um status
`code public void retirada(double valor) {
        if (valor > getSaldo()) {
            System.out.println("Valor informado maior que o saldo");
        } else {
            setSaldo(saldo - valor);
            if (getSaldo() < 50000) {
                setCategoria(SILVER);
            } else if (getSaldo() < 200000) {
                setCategoria(GOLD);
            } else {
                setCategoria(PLATINUM);
            }
        }
    }code`

Comment: Não consegui ler o código no seu comentário, ficou muito bagunçado. Atualize a pergunta com essas novas informações

Comment: Você pode usar o próprio comando [`break`](http://www.mballem.com/post/usando-break-continue-e-instrucoes-rotuladas/?i=1), só precisa entender se é realmente necessário.

Comment: editei a pergunta :)

Comment: Não entendi sua duvida, onde você quer colocar uma parada? Do jeito que está, o código deveria funcionar da forma como explicou.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Existe, se chama `return`.

Você pode encapsular sua lógica em uma função:

```
public Categoria getCategoria(int saldo) {
    if (saldo < 50000) {
        return SILVER;
    } else if (saldo < 200000) {
        return GOLD;
    } else {
        return PLATINUM;
    }
}
```

Isso supõe que os valores das versões de pokémon já foram declarados em algum outro lugar. Para integrar com o resto do código:

```
if (valor > getSaldo()) {
    System.out.println("Valor informado maior que o saldo");
} else {
    setSaldo(saldo - valor);
}
Categoria pokemon = getCategoria(getSaldo());
setCategoria(pokemon);
```

Já sobre não cair mais de uma categoria de uma vez, pra isso você vai precisar aumentar a complexidade do seu código um pouco. Não sei como você as está organizando, mas aqui vai uma sugestão:

```
Categoria categoriaAtual = getCategoria(getSaldo());
Categoria rebaixamento = getProximoRebaixamento(categoriaAtual); // implemente isto.
if (valor > getSaldo()) {
    System.out.println("Valor informado maior que o saldo");
} else {
    setSaldo(saldo - valor);
}
Categoria novaCategoria = getCategoria(getSaldo());
if (categoriaAtual != rebaixamento) {
    setCategoria(rebaixamento);
}
```

Comment: Na verdade, é uma conta bancária e já tenho essa função que tu mencionastes e, esse método que eu expus, tem que ser void. Só queria saber mesmo se existe algum tipo de break num if-else enceado, Mas, muito obrigado, seus códigos já me deram outrsa idéias :)